# Select relevant option of multiple select based on selected option of special select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

```
<select >
  <option  value="1" selected>One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
<select >
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>    
<select >
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected >Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

I have multiple select box like that  for example in first select box 1 is already selected so if i change option value 1 to 2 then change the selected value to 1 in which select box 2 is already selected

i am doing like

```
function getval(sff,sel){
    var selectval=[];
    $("select > option:selected").each(function(e) {
        if(sel.value==this.value){
            alert(this.value);
            $(this).find('option[value="2"]').prop('selected', true); 
        }
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select target option of `select` tag in change event listener of main select. So select relevant option of selects and add `selected` attribute to them.

```js
$(".main").change(function(e) {
  $(this).siblings("select").find("option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="main">
  <option value="1" selected>One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
<select >
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
<select >
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected >Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is to replace value if i select two from main then replace selected value two with one .

Comment: @kailash Browser do this automatically. Check http://jsfiddle.net/nhd6s3am/

Comment: @ Mohammad  u misunderstood  i mean when select two(2)  from <option value="1" selected>One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
then  two from  second select  <option value="2" selected >Two</option>
should replace by one(1)

Comment: can u tell me how i get siblings when all select element in <li> tag

Comment: @kailash Also use `.siblings()` in this case

Comment: @ Mohammad  not working you can also check on this  jsfiddle.net/nhd6s3am/1 one after taking select box in li

Comment: @kailash Provided jsfiddle doesn't contain `li`

Comment: please check it after adding li i checked but not working.. please help

Comment: @kailash What you mean *not working*? It work as you want *if i select two from main then replace selected value two with one*

Comment: <li>
<select >
<option value="1" selected>One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
</li>
<select >

  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
</li>
<li>
<select >
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected >Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>

</select>
</li> @ Mohammad please check know this is what i mean to say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181461/discussion-between-kailash-and-mohammad).